# When flipping through a deck of cards, what is the probability of drawing all $4$ jacks, all $4$ queens, or all $4$ aces before drawing $3$ kings?

Tags: probability, card-games

If I'm flipping through a deck of cards one-by-one and pulling each one out, what's the chance I pull all 4 jacks, all 4 queens, or all 4 aces before I pull 3 kings?

One idea I had was to compute the answer as $P(\text{draw 3 of a kind of J, Q, A before 3 of a kind of K}) \times P(\text{draw last J, Q, or A before 3rd K})$, somehow using the Negative Hypergeometric Distribution, but I don't think it works because, for example, a 3 of a kind of 2's can't be classified as a "success" or "failure" in this problem.

Comment: You can ignore all cards which are not JQKA since they don't change the outcome, and essentially think about a deck of just 16 cards.

Comment: Following on @aschepler's hint, if you were to think in terms of a 16 card deck like that... rather than talking about the first however many cards, what can you say about the last two cards specifically?  Can you find the probability that the last card is what you need it to be?  How about the second to last card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By inclusion-exclusion:

The probability all four Jacks occur before a third king is the same as the probability that the final two cards of a reduced eight-card deck (containing only jack and kings) are both kings is $\frac{4}{8}\cdot\frac{3}{7}$

The probability that all four Jacks and all four Queens occur before a third king is the same as the probability that the final two cards of a reduced twelve-card deck (containing only jacks, queens, and kings) are both kings is $\frac{4}{12}\cdot\frac{3}{11}$.

Finally, all four Jacks, Queens, *and* Aces occur before the third king is the same as the probability that the final two cards of a reduced sixteen-card deck (containing only jacks, queens, kings, and aces) are both kings is $\frac{4}{16}\cdot\frac{3}{15}$.

By symmetry, all other relevant probabilities can be found.  Letting $J$ be the event that all four Jacks occurred before the third king, and similarly defining $Q$ and $A$, we have:

$$\Pr(J\cup Q\cup A) = \Pr(J)+\Pr(Q)+\Pr(A)-\Pr(J\cap Q)-\Pr(J\cap A)-\Pr(Q\cap A)+\Pr(J\cap Q\cap A)$$

$$= 3\cdot \dfrac{4\cdot 3}{8\cdot 7} - 3\cdot\dfrac{4\cdot 3}{12\cdot 11}+\dfrac{4\cdot 3}{16\cdot 15}=\dfrac{647}{1540}\approx 0.42013$$

Comment: Great, clear answer. The use of inclusion-exclusion is nice as is breaking the problem down into smaller decks. Thank you.